# Why is this script giving an "Unexpected end of file" syntax error?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Why is this script giving an "Unexpected end of file" syntax error in the last line?

```
{ [ $# -ne 2 ] && [ $# -ne 3 ] } && { echo "Uso: $0 [opciones] [nlineasresultado] [archivos a analizar]" && echo "NEED 2 OR 3 PARAMETERS" && exit 1 }
echo sucessfull
exit 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the `bash` man page, which shows that the syntax when using braces (`{`, `}`) is:

```
{ list; }
```

This means that you are missing a couple of semicolons:

```
{ [ $# -ne 2 ] && [ $# -ne 3 ]; } && { echo "Uso: $0 [opciones] [nlineasresultado] [archivos a analizar]" && echo "NEED 2 OR 3 PARAMETERS" && exit 1; }
```

Note that you can also use newlines to achieve the same thing.  That is, this is an error:

```
{ echo hello }
```

But this works:

```
{ echo hello; }
```

As does this:

```
{
echo hello
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`bash` command grouping, `{}`, needs a `;` before the closing brace ,`}`, as you didn't have put it hence the error.

Do:

```
{ [ $# -ne 2 ] && [ $# -ne 3 ] ;} && { echo "Uso: $0 [opciones] [nlineasresultado] \
          [archivos a analizar]" && echo "NEED 2 OR 3 PARAMETERS" && exit 1 ;}
```